# When is this appropriate?

Tags: html

My co worker asked me this today and like every question I don't know the answer to I'm asking on stack overflow. When is this appropriate?

```
                       </table>
                    </ul>
                 </fieldset>
              </div>
        </span>                                        
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: When you have matching opening tags? You might need to elaborate on what you're going for.

Answer (score 1):

Only inline elements can be contained within inline elements like `span`, `a`, `i`. But block level elements like `div` cannot.

The code you provided is not appropriate.